# ->getMethod("") throws "undefined method"

Tags: php, reflection

I've been bugging with this for a while now. I've hit a complete brick wall here. I'm attempting to gather information about a method from the method name. But php doesn't know about getMethod() tho is should be a part of the "reflection" in php. (http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getmethod.php)
In the link there this dude mentioning it'll throw an error, which seems to be my case, but with no answer on it...

in my case the code looks like this:

```
$params = $controllerInstance->getMethod($methodName)->getParameters();
```

and the class looks like this:

```
class accountController extends controller{

    public function createUser(account $accountModelInstance){
        return "this is a response!";
    }

}
```

I fear this:

```
class accountController extends controller{
    public function getMethod(string method){
        return this->{method};
    }
}
```

I'm running the [WAMP Server](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) with a postgreSQL plugin if u care.

Comment: Do you think that all the methods in ReflectionClass are available to all classes? That's not the case. Look at the example for ReflectionClass. You have to instantiate it, give it the class you want to reflect on, then make your changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ReflectionClass` is a class. You don’t define anything, you just use it:

```
$class = new ReflectionClass($controllerInstance);
$params = $class->getMethod($methodName)->getParameters();
```

[It works!](http://codepad.viper-7.com/oRwpi4)

Comment: I think ill reflect upon this.